# How to use postman API client with openchain API server

Tags: rest, postman, blockchain

I have just installed openchain (http://openchain.org)

I can check it on http://nossl.wallet.openchain.org/ but I would like to check API using Postman Rest client tool on my PC.

I'm using postman rest client and I have tried URI many times but response is empty : https://docs.openchain.org/en/latest/api/method-calls.html

Please give some advises, thanks in advance !

Comment: what url are you trying?

Comment: hi, for example : http://localhost:8090/query/recordversion

Comment: Can You please let me know how you configured your server wallet configuration in ubuntu @Thanh Nguyen van

Answer (score 0):

You should want it to look like something like this picture. Check your headers also, when I use the URL https://www.openchain.org/endpoint/query/recordversion?key=FFFF I get nothing and then when I check the headers I see there is a 404 status which means I was able to communicate with the server but it couldn't find my key. Which makes sense since I am just passing a random key. So see if you are getting a 404 error in your headers and if so then make sure your key is correct.

[image: postman]